# could not get unknown property for 'applicationVariants' for BuildType_Decorated

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, build.gradle

I have imported the module in my project and its correctly imported. But i am getting this error. i have imported the Scanner control  app module (By zebra). I have searched for many alternated solutions, but it's not working out.

```
Error:(36, 0) Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[/home/custom/AndroidStudioProjects/fireball5/fireball/build/intermediates/proguard-files/proguard-android.txt-2.3.3, /home/custom/AndroidStudioProjects/fireball5/fireball/scannercontrol/proguard-rules.pro], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.
<a href="openFile:/home/custom/AndroidStudioProjects/fireball5/fireball/scannercontrol/build.gradle">Open File</a>
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zebra.scannercontrol.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 71
        versionName "2.0.8.0"
        if (project.hasProperty('ADD_BUILD_TO_VERSION')) {
            versionName = versionName.substring(0,versionName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) + (System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ?: "0")
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../../../keys/AndroidScannerSDK.keystore")
            if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD')) {
                storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD')) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                appendVersionName(variant, defaultConfig)
            }
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        // Don't abort if Lint finds an error, otherwise the Jenkins build
        // will be marked as failed, and Jenkins won't analyse the Lint output
        abortOnError false
    }
}
def appendVersionName(variant, defaultConfig) {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        if (output.zipAlign) {
            def file = output.outputFile
            def fileName = file.name.replace("scannercontrol-release.apk", "scanner_control_app_v" + defaultConfig.versionName  + ".apk")
            output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
        }

        def file = output.packageApplication.outputFile
        def fileName = file.name.replace("scannercontrol-release", "scanner_control_app_v" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk")
        output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile project(':BarcodeScannerLibrary')
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You have an error at `applicationVariants.all`.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            appendVersionName(variant, defaultConfig)
        }
    }
}
```

**Fix 1:**

This will not work since you are applying `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.

You have to change it to `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to use `applicationVariants.all`.

**Fix 2:**

If you want to keep using `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.

Change `applicationVariants.all` to `libraryVariants.all` or `testVariants.all`.

**Explanation:**

applicationVariants (only for the app plugin)

libraryVariants (only for the library plugin)

testVariants (for both plugins)

All three return a [DomainObjectCollection](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DomainObjectCollection.html) of ApplicationVariant, LibraryVariant, and TestVariant objects respectively.

Hope this helps.

### Edit:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 71
        versionName "2.0.8.0"
        if (project.hasProperty('ADD_BUILD_TO_VERSION')) {
            versionName = versionName.substring(0,versionName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) + (System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ?: "0")
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../../../keys/AndroidScannerSDK.keystore")
            if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD')) {
                storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD')) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile project(':BarcodeScannerLibrary')
}
```

Comment: Error:Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.zebra.scannercontrol.app' in default config.       (on adding testvariants.all). @Greaper

Comment: You can only set the applicationId when using `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`.

Comment: Error:(49, 0) Could not get unknown property 'zipAlign' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.LibraryVariantOutputImpl.
<a href="openFile:/home/custom/AndroidStudioProjects/fireball5/fireball/scannercontrol/build.gradle">Open File</a> (on adding libraryVaraients.all)  @Greaper.

Comment: in if condition? @Greaper

Comment: Error:(49, 0) Could not get unknown property 'zipAlign' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.TestVariantImpl.
nd also for the object of type libraryVariants. @Greaper

Comment: i want to run my main application, and want to use  scanner control as a library(module dependency). do i need to make any changes in androidmanifest.xml(Scanner control)? and will it be fine if i remove these unnecessary things from build.gradle(Scannercontrol)?  like this zipAlign and other@Greaper

Comment: So you want to use your scanner control application as library??

Comment: @BhavikMehta See edit this is what you need when using your application as library.

Comment: yes, i have already done that.1). i have imported scanner control module. 2) i have added the module dependency. 3) i have done appply plugin : "com.android.library" 4) added libraryvariants.all  5) added variant.zipAlign. 6) then i am getting zipAlign error.(which i had already mentioned). @Greaper

Comment: The method `appendVersionName` is unneed since you are not building a apk with the library. The `build.gradle` in my edit is all you need.

Comment: yes @Greaper. i have commented that part. now i can use my scanner control classes in my application.  Thank you so much