# How to build CHAQUOPY Android library (.AAR or .JAR file) in Android Studio

Tags: android, jar, android-library, aar, chaquopy

I am trying to use chaquopy https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/ android plugin for developing an android app that uses python script for some serious calculations, and I would like to make the app module as an android library (.AAR) to be able to reuse that in other project. (.eg ionic app).

When I change `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` as suggested here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library then resync project gradle, I get this error:

> Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for object of
>   type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

After googling it I get this solution: [could not get unknown property for 'applicationVariants' for BuildType_Decorated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101309/could-not-get-unknown-property-for-applicationvariants-for-buildtype-decorated)

So I change `applicationVariants.all` to `libraryVariants.all` or `testVariants.all`.

But the error is still present, and cant build the project.

Image:

[image: error]

So https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/ can not be imbedded in android library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now supported starting in Chaquopy version 8.0.0. See [the documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#gradle-plugin) for details.

> The Chaquopy plugin can also be used in an [Android library module](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) (AAR). However, it can only be used in one module in a project: either in the app module, or in exactly one library module. Attempting to use it in multiple modules will give the error “More than one file was found with OS independent path”.

Answer (score 1):

The last version of Chaquopy allows to use the plugin in a module / AAR. Only for one module per project:

> The Chaquopy plugin can also be used in an Android library module
> (AAR). However, it can only be used in one module in a project: either
> in the app module, or in exactly one library module. Attempting to use
> it in multiple modules will give the error “More than one file was
> found with OS independent path”.

Please see: https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html

Comment: Thanks: I would delete my outdated answer in favor of yours, but it doesn't allow me to delete an accepted answer, so I've edited it instead.

Comment: Great! Thanks to you, Malcolm.